# windows 7 booting from wrong drive. How to move the bootloader?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, bootloader

I had windows 7 installed on an old dying harddrive. I did a fresh install onto a new one, but it only boots from the old hard drive. theres two "Windows 7" on the list. How do i move the bootloader to my new harddrive before the old one dies completely and I lose all access.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the boot-loader: you need to change the disc order in the BIOS. Depending on how you did your install you may have to make the new disc bootable, either through the install disc, or one of the many boot utilities available.

Comment: I did try changing the boot order. When choosing  the disc i installed the fresh copy of windows, i get  a black screen with a blinking cursor forever. Only the old one goes to bootloader

Comment: If you'd installed W7 with the old drive disconnected, it would have created the boot code on the new disc. As it is you added the new installation to the existing boot code on the old drive. So you need to install the new boot code. I think you'll find that http://forums.cnet.com/7723-19411_102-373491/how-to-make-a-hard-drive-bootable/ will give you a solution.